# Mutate data frame with data from another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, date, merge, mean

**Reproducible Data:**

```
df1 <- tibble(id = c("GR1","GR2"),
              area = c("A1","A2"),
              date1 = as.Date(c("2022-01-01","2022-01-02")),
              date2 = as.Date(c("2022-01-06","2022-01-08")))

set.seed(543)
df2 <- tibble(date3 = seq(as.Date("2022-01-01"), as.Date("2022-01-09"), "days"),
              temperature =runif(9, min = 28, max = 33),
              area = c("A1","A2","A1","A2","A1","A2","A1","A2","A1"))
```

Hello,
I want to create a column in df1 with the average temperature resulting in a filter from df2. (In the real data frames I have 1036 rows in df1 and 26192 rows in df2. )

I tried this approach, but it doesn't work as I thought

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  group_by(area) %>%
  mutate(average_temp = mean(filter(.data = df2, date3 >= df1$date1 & date3 <= df1$date2 & area == df1$area)$temperature))
```

**I get this error**

Warning messages:

1: Problem while computing `average_temp = mean(...)`.

i longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

---

The expected result is

| id | area | date1 | date2 | average_temp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GR1 | A1 | 2022-01-01 | 2022-02-12 | 31.58708 |
| GR2 | A2 | 2022-01-02 | 2022-02-11 | 30.50867 |

---

This chunk of code by itself gives the expected result. So the problem must be something I'm not seeing in the iteration of rows withing the logic in mutate and dplyr syntax.

```
mean(filter(.data = df2, date3 >= df1$date1[2] & date3 <= df1$date2[2] & area == df1$area[2])$temperature)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a non-equi or range-based join. Unfortunately, `dplyr` by itself cannot do that, so we need the help of another package. Options below:

### fuzzyjoin

```r
fuzzyjoin::fuzzy_left_join(
  df1, df2,
  by = c("area", date1="date3", date2="date3"),
  match_fun=list(`==`, `<=`, `>=`)
) %>%
  group_by(id, date1, date2) %>%
  summarize(
    area = area.x[1],
    avg = mean(temperature)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()
# `summarise()` has grouped output by 'id', 'date1'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# # A tibble: 2 x 5
#   id    date1      date2      area    avg
#   <chr> <date>     <date>     <chr> <dbl>
# 1 GR1   2022-01-01 2022-01-06 A1     31.6
# 2 GR2   2022-01-02 2022-01-08 A2     30.5
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
DT1 <- as.data.table(df1)
DT2 <- as.data.table(df2)
DT1[DT2, avg := ave(i.temperature, id, FUN = mean),
    on = .(area, date1 <= date3, date2 >= date3) ]
#        id   area      date1      date2      avg
#    <char> <char>     <Date>     <Date>    <num>
# 1:    GR1     A1 2022-01-01 2022-01-06 31.58708
# 2:    GR2     A2 2022-01-02 2022-01-08 30.50867
```

(I *know* there's a more canonical way to do this without `ave`, but I ran out of time ...)

### sqldf

```r
# library(sqldf) # not required to load, per se
sqldf::sqldf(
  "select df1.id, df1.area, df1.date1, df1.date2,
     avg(df2.temperature) as avg
   from df1
     left join df2 on df1.area=df2.area
       and df2.date3 between df1.date1 and df1.date2
   group by df1.id, df1.area, df1.date1, df1.date2")
#    id area      date1      date2      avg
# 1 GR1   A1 2022-01-01 2022-01-06 31.58708
# 2 GR2   A2 2022-01-02 2022-01-08 30.50867
```

Comment: Thank your for your solutions.I will use the fuzzy version. I'ts slow when processing all the data, but does the job.